# Passwords for online and offline applications

Tags: passwords

The recommended password length for offline applications (e.g. disk encryption) is at least 12-14 characters while for online applications (e.g. Web-based login) is at least 8-10 characters. 
What is the crucial difference between the two applications that makes it possible to make do with shorter passwords in the online case?

Answer (score 1):

Where do you get these standards from?

Offline passwords are stored on the users machine and thus an attacker has access to them if he gains access to the machine.

Online passwords are usually stored in a database that has its own security as an added protection layer. Also depending on where the database is stored, there is also a layer of abstraction between the app and the database so if an attacker some how manages to gain access to a DB, he may not know the context of the data he is accessing.

Although this is all conjecture as I have not come across these standards that you speak of.

Comment: To be honest it is a question in an exercise I was given and I couldn't find any references for these standards as well...

Comment: Ok. Maybe update the question when you have their supposed answer. I would be interested in their thought process.

Comment: So the answer is: The decisive difference is that online applications induce a delay for the attacker, due to the need for
the server to respond (network latency, server CPU). In an offline attack, the only limitations are in the attacker’s own hardware.